# dplyr to paste columns together in remote DB

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, paste

I'd like to paste two columns together in a remote database using dplyr. I've tried something like this:

```
mydb %>%
    select(A, B) %>%
    mutate(newcol = paste(A, B, collapse = "_"))
```

But I get an error saying `Error in paste(A, B, collapse = "_") : object 'A' not found` . What is `dplyr`'s translation of paste?

I tried:

```
> translate_sql(paste(x, y, sep = "_"))
<SQL> PASTE("x", "y", '_' AS "sep")
```

So I plugged that syntax in to attempt:

```
mydb %>%
    select(A, B) %>%
    mutate(newcol = PASTE("A", "B", "_" AS "sep"))
```

but using that didn't work either, with the error of `Named arguments ignored for SQL PASTE`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

`paste()` concatenates only list of elements separated by `collapse`'s value.  since you have only one value here, the correct way is to use `sep`. Also whole column is considered in `paste()`, so `group_by` is used to separate them.

```
mydb %>%
    group_by(A, B) %>%
    mutate(newcol = paste(A, B, sep = "_"))
```